# Partition Berkeley DB SQL API database

Tags: sql, database, berkeley-db

Is it possible to have Berkeley DB partitioned when using SQL API? I found out that Berkeley DB supports partitioning (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/am_partition.html) with BTree and Hash access methods. But there is no explanation weather it is possible to do it with SQL API. My idea is to create raw Berkeley DB partitioned and then open it using SQL API. Does anyone tried to partition SQL API Berkeley DB?

Answer (score 1):

David Segleau, Director of Product Management for Berkeley DB here. Generally, we recommend that people ask questions on the [Berkeley DB forums](http://bit.ly/e5KwzV). You'll find a large community of active Berkeley DB application developers there.

The short answer to your question is "Not yet". The BDB engineering team is busy integrating BDB features with the SQLite API. The important thing for us is to think through the implementation so that it's very easy to use and is a "natural" extension for a SQLite developer. Stay tuned to a future BDB release near you.

In the meantime, in BDB partitioned databases are are mostly syntactic sugar. It's actually implemented as a special case, with separate tables used for storage underneath. You can accomplish close to the same behavior by splitting the data into separate tables and modifying your application to get/put data into the appropriate table as you would today. Does that help?

As we work on prioritizing which BDB features to integrate next, it's always useful to hear from our users about how they use the product. Can you describe how table partitioning would be used in your application and what technical requirements or problems it would solve?

Thanks,

Dave